Handling a large matrix with numpy efficiently
I am trying to run some simple calculations on a quite large matrix; roughly, 200Kx200K or real numbers. I need to obtain l1-norm, i.e., the sum of absolute values. Here is a similar question with addresses the question of absolute values. The problem is, thus, not how to obtain absolute values and to sum them up, but how to handle large matrices/arrays efficiently. Here is the code:
results = np.abs(mtx).sum(dim='rows')

Unfortunately, the code crashes even on the server, allocating a lot of memory. What would be the efficient way to handle this? Would using float32 make a difference? The number should be rather small.

How did you succeed to get mtx into memory?

Where do you get the data from? From a multiple Terabyte disk storing one file?

Does if fail with just the np.abs(mtx) operation? That creates a new matrix which would double your memory footprint. But you could do np.abs(mtx, out=mtx) to write back to the same matrix instead.

200Kx200K is 40 billion elements. just saying, think about it.

maximdu pointed out that np.abs can allocate a new matrix. But just use np.abs(mtx, out=mtx) to do the conversion in place.
This is a common theme in numpy. np.sum will also need out=mtx

sum outputs a different sized array so out=mtx won't work.
